# Proving that G must have an area bordered by maximum of 5 edges

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I am working on this proof about planar graphs:

Let G be a planar and connected Graph where every node has a degree higher than or equal to $3$. Show that G must have an area bordered by a maximum of $5$ edges.

I started by a proof by contradiction so assumed that every area gets bordered by a minimum of $6$ edges. I then created the following inequalities: $2 \cdot e \ge 3 \cdot v$ (Handshaking Lemma) and
$f \le 1/3 e$. I tried plugging those values into the Eulers polyhedron formula but I am struggling since I don't have much experience with inequalities, especially when it comes to plugging them into equalities. I would appreciate any help! :)

Answer (score 2):

$2=v-e+f\le \frac{2e}{3}-e+\frac e3=0$ gives a contradiction.

Comment: Is there limit or are there certain aspects that one has to consider when plugging inequalities into equalities? Because even after seeing the solution, I still don't think I would be satisfied because the value of e is not fixed so how can I be sure that the  equation yields  0 for every possible value that e can get?

Comment: One can reason as follows. Let us assume that the inequalities $v<2e/3$ and $f<e/3$ are strict, for the sake of simplicity. Consider some value $A$ which equals $v-e+f$. Initially $A$ equals $2$. Now let us put $2e/3$ instead of $v$. It will make $A$ greater because you removed one summand and put a greater one instead. The same with replacing $f$. $A$ becomes even greater and is far beyond its initial value $2$. But! It turns out that $A$ equals $0$ now! Which is less than $2$. How could it be that we made a value greater and greater and it decreased as a result?!